# How to retain the observable array object dependency when knockout item UI order is changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have observable array binding for my HTML table columns.
User can change the table column Order using drag and drop option.
When a column order is changed from UI, the dependency between the UI for that column and observable array is no more exists.

So any change in the observable array is not reflecting UI?

My question is, How to retain the dependency between UI and its item in the observable array.

My view model

```
 var ViewModelInfo={  
HeaderColumnList: ko.observableArray([])
};
```

HTML is

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr data-bind="foreach : HeaderColumnList">
<th data-bind="text : ColumnName">
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</thead>
</table>
```

There are options to change th order,
1)  through UI(using drag and drop) 
2)  through sort function of knockout observable array.
when it is changed through UI, the UI element lost dependency between respective observable item element.

Comment: We'll need more context to help you. The answer is probably to use a computed, but... Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have updated sample code, please let me know if anything is required.

Comment: That doesn't help, not least because you've left out the most important part: How you modify the array. Create a **runnable** example that **demonstrates** the problem. If you modify that array via observableArray methods (or by setting a new array), the UI will reflect the changes. Details [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

Comment: Also, what library have you used (if any) to implement the drag and drop feature?